# Change Step Order in Checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout

I'm trying to change the order of the steps in the magento onepage checkout. What I need to do is to move the Review step before the Payment selection.

I've looked on the internet for a solution but everything I found was to change the order in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

I've tried it, but nothing changed.

What I did was creating a file inside `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`and inside this file I've changed the line 208 in:

```
   protected function _getStepCodes()
{
    return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping', 'shipping_method', 'review', 'payment');
}
```

what am I missing here?

(I'm using Magento 1.9.1.1)

Answer (score 2):

Also there are few files,where you need change  code

- *`OnepageController.php`* at *`app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controller/.`*  here,  step *html/content* render content basic of calling function.

In  default magento  ***saveShippingAction()*** function save *shipping method Info and render payment step content*.

```
        $result['update_section'] = array(
            'name' => 'payment-method',
            'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
        );
```

But for your case,you want to render  review step content.so You need to change it

```
        $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
        $result['update_section'] = array(
            'name' => 'review',
            'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
        );
```

- `skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js`

Comment: I can't understand what I need to change, sorry.